# 正規表現についての質問

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

正規表現についてです。
(y|yes|はい|ok|おｋ)
だけが入力されたときだけtrueにしたいのです。
yearとかはtrueにしたくないのです。
現在は、上記の言葉のいずれかがmessageに内に含まれているかを調べていますが、
yなどが付くスペルを入力すると、反応してしまいます。
これを反応しないようにしたいんです。
どうすればいいのでしょうか？

```
//meaasegeは変数で、ユーザからの入力のデータを入れています。
const yesExp = /(y|yes|はい|ok|おｋ)/;
clearExp.test(meaasege)
```

Comment: messageに「含まれている」という意味では正解かと思いますが、実際はmessageと「完全一致」するものだけを反応させたいのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません。言葉足らずでした。Meaaseg内に入っている値例えば「year」とすれば、現状ですと、yが含まれているため、trueとなりますが、trueにしたくないのです。

Comment: 正規表現は一致したくない条件を書くのは不得意で、一致したい条件軸で検討したほうが考えやすいです。trueにしたい条件例を書いてもらえると正しい条件が設定できると思います。

Answer (score 2):

文字列先頭と末尾を検索条件に加えて

```
/^(y|yes|はい|ok|おｋ)$/
```

としてください